# How to change columns type in numpy ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Because I do not understand numpy dtypes, I have to create Pandas and then I can change type of columns. But that is wrong way because of memory consumption.  If I have  pandas columns like that:

```
df[0 ] = df[0 ].astype(np.int64)
df[1 ] = df[1 ].astype(np.int8)
df[2 ] = df[2 ].astype(np.int8)
df[3 ] = df[3 ].astype(np.int8)
df[4 ] = df[4 ].astype(np.int8)
df[5 ] = df[5 ].astype(np.int8)
df[6 ] = df[6 ].astype(np.int8)
df[7 ] = df[7 ].astype(np.int8)
df[8 ] = df[8 ].astype(np.int8)
df[9 ] = df[9 ].astype(np.int8)
df[10 ] = df[10 ].astype(np.int16)
df[11] = df[11].astype(np.float64)
df[12] = df[12].astype(np.int16)
df[13] = df[13].astype(np.int16)
df[14] = df[14].astype(np.int8)
df[15] = df[15].astype(np.float64)
df[16] = df[16].astype(np.int16)
df[17] = df[17].astype(np.int16)
df[18] = df[18].astype(np.int8)
```

If numpy ndarray have for example a shape (55541, 19), how can I change type of columns:

```
df[0 ] = df[0 ].astype(np.int64)
df[1 ] = df[1 ].astype(np.int8)
df[10 ] = df[10 ].astype(np.int16)
df[11] = df[11].astype(np.float64)
```

I tired to do the same for ndarray:

```
arr[:, 0 ] = arr[:, 0 ].astype(np.int64)
```

but does not work.

I want to have right column type after reading ndarray from pickle file.

Thank you for answer.

Comment: look at `dt.to_records()`.  That's a structured array with mixed dtypes in the fields.

Comment: A numpy array has one `dtype`, applicable to all elements.  A `structured array` (`recarray`) has a compound dtype, where each `field` has its own `dtype`, much like what you create with the dataframe.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html